# HTML & Js Color Picker: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, colors

The problem is, no matter what control you're on, it will just affect the blue color.

I'm guessing it might have something to do with the fact that I'm declaring the controls and assigning their handlers in a loop, but I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong or if the solution is to just do that manually, one by one.

[Here's](http://jsbin.com/cikureliro/1/edit?html,js,output) a copy of the project.

```
let 
  // This one will contain all the elements
  picker = document.createElement("div")
  // And this one the color controls
, values = document.createElement("form")
  // This' the color preview
, preview = document.createElement("div")
  // The preview initializes and updates based on this values
, colors = { red : 200, green : 0, blue : 0 }
  // This validates if a value is between 0 and 255
, vv = { min : 0, max : 255 }
, validVal = (n) => vv.min <= n && n <= vv.max
  // And this' just a style string
, style = ""
;

// This one changes preview's bg color and shows the 
// value inside it
function updatePreview() {
  let rgbString = 
    "rgb(" 
  + [colors.red, colors.green, colors.blue].join(",") 
  + ")";

  preview.style["background-color"] = rgbString;
  preview.innerHTML = rgbString;
}

// Now we define the elements' class names
picker.className  += " color-picker"; 
values.className  += " rgb-values";
preview.className += " preview";

// And their appearance
style += "display : inline-block;";
values.style = style;

style += "width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid #000;";
preview.style = style;

// Then we add'em to the screen
picker.appendChild(values);
picker.appendChild(preview);
document.body.appendChild(picker);

// And, "finally", we add the controls and their handlers
// One for each color
for (var color in colors) {
  // This are text and slide controls
  let  
    label = document.createElement("label")
  , span  = document.createElement("span")
  , slide = document.createElement("input")
  , text  = document.createElement("input")
  ;

  // We define their general attributes
  label.style = "display: block";

  slide.name = color + "-slide";
  slide.type = "range";
  slide.min  = vv.min;
  slide.max  = vv.max;
  slide.step = "1";

  text.name = color + "-text";
  text.type = "text";
  text.size = "3";

  span.innerHTML = " " + color;

  // And set their initial values
  slide.value = text.value = colors[color];

  // We add'em to screen also
  label.appendChild(slide);
  label.appendChild(text);
  label.appendChild(span);
  values.appendChild(label);

  // And now the handlers
  /* 
    This is the tricky part. 
    I must be doing something wrong here. I guess.
    Pls, help!
  */
  function slideHandler(e) {
    text.value = slide.value;
    colors[color] = slide.value;
    updatePreview();
  }

  slide.oninput = slideHandler;

  function textHandler(e) {
    if (validVal(text.value)) slide.value = text.value;
    colors[color] = slide.value;
    updatePreview();
  }

  text.onchange = textHandler; 
}

// And... Showtime!
updatePreview();
```

Comment: are all those leading commas typos?

Comment: @Cruiser No, sorry to distract you with that. I know it's not conventional, that's just how I like to declare variables in a row.

Comment: @itiel did my answer help or did you run into a problem?

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO it did, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `var` color for `slide.name.split('-')[0]`

CODE:

```
  function slideHandler(e) {(
    text.value = slide.value;
    colors[slide.name.split('-')[0]] = slide.value;
    updatePreview();)}
```

```js
(function() {
  window.onload = function() {
    let
      // This one will contain all the elements
      picker = document.createElement("div")
      // And this one the color controls
      ,
      values = document.createElement("form")
      // This' the color preview
      ,
      preview = document.createElement("div")
      // The preview initializes and updates based on this values
      ,
      colors = {
        red: 200,
        green: 0,
        blue: 0
      }
      // This validates if a value is between 0 and 255
      ,
      vv = {
        min: 0,
        max: 255
      },
      validVal = (n) => vv.min <= n && n <= vv.max
      // And this' just a style string
      ,
      style = "";

    // This one changes preview's bg color and shows the 
    // value inside it
    function updatePreview() {
      let rgbString =
        "rgb(" +
        [colors.red, colors.green, colors.blue].join(",") +
        ")";

      preview.style["background-color"] = rgbString;
      preview.innerHTML = rgbString;
    }

    // Now we define the elements' class names
    picker.className += " color-picker";
    values.className += " rgb-values";
    preview.className += " preview";

    // And their appearance
    style += "display : inline-block;";
    values.style = style;

    style += "width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid #000;";
    preview.style = style;

    // Then we add'em to the screen
    picker.appendChild(values);
    picker.appendChild(preview);
    document.body.appendChild(picker);

    // And, "finally", we add the controls and their handlers
    // One for each color
    for (var color in colors) {
      // This are text and slide controls
      let
        label = document.createElement("label"),
        span = document.createElement("span"),
        slide = document.createElement("input"),
        text = document.createElement("input");

      // We define their general attributes
      label.style = "display: block";

      slide.name = color + "-slide";
      slide.type = "range";
      slide.min = vv.min;
      slide.max = vv.max;
      slide.step = "1";

      text.name = color + "-text";
      text.type = "text";
      text.size = "3";

      span.innerHTML = " " + color;

      // And set their initial values
      slide.value = text.value = colors[color];

      // We add'em to screen also
      label.appendChild(slide);
      label.appendChild(text);
      label.appendChild(span);
      values.appendChild(label);

      // And now the handlers
      /* 
        This is the tricky part. 
        I must be doing something wrong here. I guess.
        Pls, help!
      */
      function slideHandler(e) {
        text.value = slide.value;
        colors[slide.name.split('-')[0]] = slide.value;
        updatePreview();
      }

      slide.oninput = slideHandler;

      function textHandler(e) {
        if (validVal(text.value)) slide.value = text.value;
        colors[slide.name.split('-')[0]] = slide.value;
        updatePreview();
      }

      text.onchange = textHandler;
    }

    // And... Showtime!
    updatePreview();
  };
})();
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
```

Comment: Oh, wow. Turns out you're right. Yes, I aslo had to do it on the `text` handler and it works out just fine. For some reason i can't upvote your answer, but that's the one, thanks. On the other hand, why do you think it wouldn't work the other way?

Comment: @itiel I didnt really look into where your ``color`` variable was coming from but i did see it had the value ``blue`` as default. You can use that variable but change it on the listeners. Im glad it helped.